How can I keep the correct tenant context for each async operation when using InheritableThreadLocal?
I have a multi-tenant Spring application that processes messages from RabbitMQ. Each message sets a tenant context in an InheritableThreadLocal. After handling a message, I start an asynchronous database call with a delay (Thread.sleep).
If another message arrives on the same thread before the async operation finishes, the InheritableThreadLocal is updated to a new tenant. This means the still-running async call ends up using the wrong tenant.
Example:
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(extractTenantFrom(msg));
    asyncService.doAsyncWork(); 
}

public void doAsyncWork() {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // Perform database operation using TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()
}

I assumed InheritableThreadLocal would keep the original tenant context stable for each async operation. Instead, new messages arriving on the same thread overwrite the tenant. I expected each async call to remain tied to its original tenant, not get mixed up when threads are reused.
How can I fix this problem?

Async and thread contexts just don't mix. The whole point of async is that your operations are no longer executed by some thread, and are bounced between them when not doing I/O.
